# Problem Loading Splash Screen Nib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, xcode4

I have an application which loads a lot of data. I have the data loading on a separate thread, but while it loads I would like to show a splash screen. For the splash screen I created a NIB file, but I can't get the NIB to display. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. If anyone can help, I'd greatly appreciate it. Here is the code:

Header file:

```
@interface DigiWireCDAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    --
    UIWindow *window;
    --
    UIView *loadingView;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingAnimationIndicator;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
--
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *loadingView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingAnimationIndicator;
--
```

Implementation:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [self loadData];

    [loadingAnimationIndicator startAnimating];
    loadingView.hidden = NO;

    [window addSubview:loadingView];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:loadingView];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

In case this helps, here is the NIB:

[image: loadView NIB]

Comment: Is this splash screen in the MainWindow.xib?

Comment: No, it's a separate NIB called loadingView.xib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you have something set as an IBOutlet doesn't mean the xib will load automatically. In your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` you want to `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"loadingView" owner:self options:nil];` in order to actually load the xib into memory.

Comment: Thanks much - that did the trick. I've been searching around for a few hours but I guess my google-foo wasn't there for me today.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's in [self loadData] but I have guess that it does its work on the main thread and therefore it's blocking the UI from updating.  You need to give the run loop a chance to run in order to have the activity indicator start animating.  Either run loadData on a background thread, if that's possible, or use performSelector:withDelay: to run it after a short amount of time (like 0.1) just so the run loop has a chance to tick over.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, loadData creates a new thread and runs the data loading routine on it. In my tests I've actually had [self loadData] commented out to be sure it wasn't causing any problems. For some reason the NIB still doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

Is your png actually being copied int resulting package? Maybe your Image View points to an image somewhere on your filesystem instead of the package.